# Highlight Side Nav on Scroll in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, nav

I want to make my Side Nav change its color when I scroll down my page in angular
I know about host listeners but I'm not getting the idea of how I can implement them in my project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure host listeners is one way to listen for scroll events.

```js
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll($event) {
      console.log("scrolling...");
  }
```

But maybe you want to listen for something specific?

```html
    <div #element (scroll)="onScroll(element)">
```

You could then use `[NgStyle]` to give your sidenav a color based on some value?

```js
 myColor = 'red';

 onScroll(element) {
  console.log("scrolling...");
  console.log(element.scrollTop)

  if (element.scrollTop > 100) {
    this.myColor = 'blue';
  }
  
 }
```

```html
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': myColor }"
```